# light weight disk based backup solution

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, rsync

Currently I am using [Dirvish](http://dirvish.org/) to backup a handful remote machines, both Linux and Windows to local disks. But Dirvish hasn't seen any updates for many years and it has a couple of small annoyances (e.g. deleting the last successful backup when it expires by age).

Dirvish features I currently use include (and thus require):

- pre-client - to dump databases to flat files on remote system
- post-server - for basic analysis of changed files in backup set
- connect to remote clients using rsync over ssh

Are there any alternatives for Dirvish available that are actively being maintained? Now I did a Google search myself and I did find one alternative, but I am looking for your *experience*; does the package work for you and why?

Comment: I'm guessing you'll have to do scripting to get the extra features with most software available. I've been liking pdumpfs and rdiff-backup for disk-based backups over time.

Comment: Have a look at rsnapshot; it has worked well for me but I haven't checked the maintainance situation recently. I believe it meets your three requirements. Here's some more: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52868/4801

Comment: This post describes a patch for dirvish where the most recent successful image is no longer being expired: http://www.mail-archive.com/dirvish@dirvish.org/msg01457.html

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed a number of backup solutions and just scraped them. Currently I use only ZFS for backups and that's why:

1. There are good configurable scripts for managing snapshots the way I like.
2. Transparent compression whenever I go with ability to look into each snapshot like just any other file system.
3. Ability to create difference steams in case rsync is too cumbersome (yeah, I have some folders >10G and more than 100'000 files -- rsync makes hard drives burn syncing them).
4. Latest versions can ditch writing data to files if blocks wasn't changed. Just imagine rewriting a 1G file adding only 100M to target fs.

The only thing I was missing was replicating remote filesystem differentially and I just wrote a script for that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [r1soft](http://www.idera.com/productssolutions/freetools/serverbackupfree) we have been using it for the past 2 years and it suits our requirement, especially the bare metal restore.